# Unable to delete a desktop folder

Tags: c#

Problem: I am unable to delete a folder (including contents) within a
desktop folder programatically with C#. If I copy the value of
desktopDestinationPath and paste it into Windows Explorer, I can open
this folder (conclusion, the path is valid) The test -
Directory.Exists(desktopDestinationPath) - returns as true and I drop
into the code block (conclusion, the path is valid)
Directory.Delete(desktopDestinationPath, true) - throws exception
(conclusion, path no longer valid) If I copy the path value from the
exception and paste it into Windows Explorer, I can open this folder
(conclusion, the path is valid)

What I have tried: Build, Rebuild, Clean Solution, restart visual
studio. Also, If I delete the folder manually and run the code, the
folder is successfully built. However, when I run a second time, I get
the exception.   Result: Puzzled look and this post. Sorry if I put
too much detail. I am open to help with a solution and criticism on
how I posted (both will help me learn) Thanks in advance!    Visual
Studio Info is toward the bottom of this entry. I am using: Microsoft
Visual Studio Premium 2013 (C#).

My code:

```
    // preceded by other code in the method
    if (Directory.Exists(desktopDestinationPath)) // desktopDestinationPath is "C:\\Users\<me>\\Desktop\\<folder 1>\\<folder 2>"
    {
        Directory.Delete(desktopDestinationPath, true); // exception is thrown here <***> "C:\\Users\\<me>\\Desktop\\<folder 1>\\<folder 2>"            
        // create folder
        Directory.CreateDirectory(desktopDestinationPath);
        // Call a method to perform Xcopy
        ProcessXcopy(SourceLoc, desktopDestinationPath);
    }
    // followed by an else which creates folder if it does not exist
```

My code is throwing the following exception: // NOTE I am using Pri.Longpath

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2147024893 Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\ljones\Desktop\folder 1\folder2\fldr3\fldr4\fldr5\fldr6\fldr7\fldr8\fldr9'. Source=mscorlib StackTrace: at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound) at  System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String path, Boolean recursive) at UnitTests.GatMinerTest.CreateDesktopDestinationFolder(String desktopPath) in c:\Users\some folder\Source\Workspaces\some folder\some folder\some folder\some file:line 93 at UnitTests.GatMinerTest.IcwIntegrationMethod() in c:\Users\some folder\Source\Workspaces\some folder\some folder\some folder\some file:line 65 InnerException:

From the web I have learned:  A DirectoryNotFoundException exception
is thrown when part of a file path or a directory is not found. Verify
that the directory appears in the specified location. Check that the
directory exists in the specified location. // I am fairly (99.9%)
certain the directory exists When using relative paths, make sure the
current directory is correct. The path may be incorrect if you are
assuming an incorrect current directory. // I am fairly (99.9%)
certain the directory exists

Comment: Please reformat your question. You can indent code 4 spaces to get syntax highlighting and code blocks.

Comment: you are using a satic path ?

Comment: Nevermind if you saw previous comment- saw the error code you posted. Can you post the code that is doing this? Most likely you have a string formatting problem. Are you escaping literals correctly? example: `"C:\\SomeFolder\\SomeOtherFolder"` or `@"C:\SomeFolder\SomeOtherFolder"`

Comment: You don't need to post what tools you  have installed on your machine - it is irrelevant information.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on how-to post.

Comment: Concerning Static and string formatting comment I have added:

create var
var desktopPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "<folder 1>");
the call:
var desktopDestinationPath = CreateDesktopDestinationFolder(desktopPath);

Comment: you have a folder on your desktop which name is `<folder 1>`? i don't think so

Comment: Your observation is correct, However "<folder 1>" in my code and on my desktop share the same name.  If there is a better way to ask the question without disclosing my path, I am open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Your path is already disclosed in exception message. And it would help if you told us what exactly is desktopDestinationPath. "'C:\Users\ljones\Desktop\\\\\\\\\'" in exception message looks really suspicious.

Comment: Yes I did (with look of embarrassment) Thanks for pointing that out. Hopefully, I have successfully edited it out now. Thanks.

Comment: I edited your post.  The angle brackets in your exception (e. g. <some folder>) were causing some of the text to be stripped out by SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help in finding an answer. Specifically, thanks for the tips on posting a question in a more appropriate manner.

The solution was an error on my part (go figure).

In code that I did not disclose, there is a call to xcopy.  I believe during testing, I had ran past that point and xcopy was working in the background (still had its hooks into my folder structure). Therefore, I couldn't delete it.

My apologies if I wasted your time. Your nudges helped push me toward finding the error in my ways.

Thanks again!